# Chain noisy after immersive wax

Tags: wax

I decided to try immersive waxing of my chain, primarily for the cleanliness. I've been following the guides on Zero Friction Cycling, but the chain is very noisy after waxing and does not improve after several rides. It's a rattling sound.

This is the process I followed:

1. Stripped the new chain of factory grease using several baths of
   mineral/white spirit followed by several washes in methylated spirit/denatured alcohol to remove any film.
2. Fully dried the chain using a hairdryer.
3. Put the chain into a
   slow cooker pot with the wax and turned on the slow cooker to the
   low setting.
4. Once the wax had fully melted I swished the chain
   for around a minute and ensured no air bubbles were seen.
5. Took out the chain, once dry I broke each link in and attached it back to the
   bike.

After a few rides I re-waxed the chain but this didn't help.

To try and confirm the factory grease was fully removed, I cleaned the chain again but this time with some bike degreaser then re-waxed. I also left the chain in the wax until it started to set, but it still sounds the same.

I'm using Silca wax.
My bike group set is Shimano GRX 400.
Chain is 10 speed Shimano HG54.

Zero Friction Cycling mention that 10 speed chains can become noisy and require rewaxing more frequently, but nothing about them being noisy immediately. The noise isn't present with a wet lubed chain.

Is there anything obvious I'm not doing correctly, or is it just a case of the chain not being suitable?

Comment: Shimano chains should be silent after an immersive wax. After the first time you stripped the chain of grease, was the chain totally dry to the touch? That is, if you wiped the chain with a clean white towel, there's not even a smudge. If you rattle the chain, it really rattles. That's a completely clean chain.

Comment: When I tried again at the weekend, starting from scratch following another degrease, the chain was dry to the touch. I left it for about an hour then blasted it with a hair dryer for a few minutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you're doing everything right.

I wax and one of my bikes has HG54 10 speed chain.  Your description matches my method with only minor variations.

- I use a garage hot air gun to dry the chain after cleaning in an ultrasonic cleaner.  Effectively the same as yours.
- For wax I use a plain lump of Paraffin wax, and I melt it in an old electric frypan that I have taken any teflon/non stick layer off.
- I let the wax heat until the chain is no longer bubbling from any point.  An IR thermometer shows a temp of 160-180 degrees C and the wax moves like "slightly stiff water" 
  **What temperature does your wax mix get to?** and what does the packaging say it should get to?
- I turn the cooker off and let it cool for ~5 minutes.  There is maybe the barest hint of a skin forming, but no more.
- Then I use a wire to catch each chain and carefully haul it out.  The wax is still hot enough to burn and molten enough to splash so be careful.
- I lay the hot chain out in a straight-ish line on corrugated cardboard, with one 180 degree turn in about the middle.  This helps at reinstallation.

Note that re-fitting the waxxed chain can drop flakes of wax on the floor, which will make a mess and can be slippery on garage floors.  Guess how I found that out.

I do not wax a quicklink or master link.   I also don't thouroughly degrease the chain if it was previously waxxed, just wipe it and shove it in the ultrasonic cleaner to remove surface dirt.  The cleaner doesn't get hot enough to melt the old remaining wax, though too much hot air to dry it can.

There's nothing inherently different about a 10 speed vs any other size of chain.

I'd be curious to know, can you feel any detectable play between adjacent chain links, on the bike when dirty and straight after cleaning, and then any play should reduce to almost nothing once the waxxing is done and cooled.

Comment: I found that the rattle was caused by stiff links even though shifting etc. was fine. They were still stiff even after over 10 rides. I took the chain off, loosened each link and that solved it. It took a long time so hopefully I can find an alternative!